# Need help understanding why nothing is drawing to screen in OpenGL, glut

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 2d, transformation

Can anyone explain what's going on or not going on so that I can correct it. Here's the code so far from a .cpp file. Running in Visual Studio Community 2015.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

const int screenWidth = 640;
const int screenHeight = 480;
```

Here `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, & `dd` are used to map the world coordinates to screen coordinates. I printed them out to make sure it was working correctly and the coordinates are being calculated correctly. In this case 0 < radius <= 5.

```
void drawHex(GLdouble radius, GLdouble aa, GLdouble bb, GLdouble cc, GLdouble dd) {
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        glVertex2d(((cos(i / 6.0 * 2 * M_PI) * radius) * aa) + cc,
                   ((sin(i / 6.0 * 2 * M_PI) * radius) * bb) + dd); 
  }
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}
```

Here I calculate `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` to map the world to the view and pass them to the `drawHex` function.

```
void myDisplay(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  GLdouble winWidth = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
  GLdouble winHeight = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
  GLdouble A, B, C, D;
  glViewport((GLint)0, (GLint)0, (GLint)winWidth, (GLint)winHeight);
  A = winWidth / 10.0;
  B = winHeight / 10.0;
  C = 0 - (A * -5.0);
  D = 0 - (B * -5.0);
  drawHex(0.5, A, B, C, D);
}
```

Program inits and main loop.

```
void myInit() {
  glClearColor(0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
  glutCreateWindow("Window");
  myInit();
  glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

All I get is a blank window with the background color. I'm expecting a hexagon in the middle of the view (not yet resized to maintain a proper aspect ratio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `gluOrtho2D` you pass [-5, 5] as bounds on both dimensions. In your calculation, anything going beyond this would be clipped out and will not be visible. Lets see if this is the case.

The `aa`, `bb`, `cc` and `dd` you pass are constants; they always remain: `64`, `48`, `320` and `240`. The value you'd get after correcting the above issue will always be within [-1, 1] since that's the codomain of `cos` and `sin` functions. This gets multiplied with `radius * aa` and added to `cc`. So worst case would be `(1 * 0.5 * 64) + 320 = 352`, which is clearly outside the `-5` boundary you'd set via `gluOrtho2D`.

The same observations apply to `y` too. Do your math on paper first and then code this up. Make sure all the boundary conditions are within limits.

It's recommended that you pass `GLUT_DOUBLE` to avoid flickers and as the other answer mentions, you need swap buffers at the end of the display function for double buffering to work. Read the answer to [Difference between single buffered(GLUT_SINGLE) and double buffered drawing(GLUT_DOUBLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28298540/183120) for details. Also, you don't need to call `glViewport` on every rendering call, instead put it in your `init` function.

Comment: I thought that the `gluOrtho2D` was used to create a virtual coordinate system? In my case a square from -5 to 5. I also thought that the `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, and `dd` values were used to map this to screen coordinates which would obviously range from (0,0) to (window width, window height) which is very far from (-5, 5), but I was expecting that. Or am I wrong about `gluOrtho2d`?

Comment: I see now, the `glVertex2d` does this math for me. I don't need to worry about mapping it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with glut but try adding glutSwapBuffers(); to the end of your drawing function. In OpenGL, there is always one frame being displayed to the user and one frame that is being rendered. Swapbuffers swaps these two frames: it sends the rendered frame to the user and pulls back the previous frame for further rendering.

Comment: I have `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);` which means that I am only using one buffer. I have also tried switching to `GLUT_DOUBLE` and have called `glutSwapBuffers();` at the end of the `myDisplay()` function. Still no hexagon.